# sharing variables between 2 different software modules in c

Tags: c, architecture, driver, shared-memory, wireless

I am trying to make some changes to the atheros wireless driver.

I am trying to find a way for passing the value of "rx_stats->rs_rssi" from recv.c (./drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/recv.c)

to the file wme.c

(/net/mac80211/wme.c)

my goal is to use the rssi value for smarter queuing choices.

Answer (score 3):

Create an API in recv.c (exported in recv.h) which returns the value in question. This allows any module that needs it access to the value.

Comment: Indeed. Avoid global variables. Return the RSSI from a function, by value.